# Why does my recent calls list have entries from the future?

Tags: iphone, ios, call

My iPhone's recent calls list correctly shows all the calls I've made or recieved, but some of them apparently have timestamps from the future:

[image]

This screenshot was taken on Jan 7th. The call labelled "1:15 PM" was made that day. The ones at the top of the list, labelled 1/12/13, were actually made sometime the previous week.

I was messing around with the phone's date and time in response to the Do Not Disturb bug. I had switched "Set time automatically" off, and changed the phone's date manually -- probably to 1/12 though I don't recall exactly -- and left it that way (actually forgot about it) for a while. My phone's time was definitely manually set incorrectly when those calls happened, and that seems pretty likely to be the cause.

I suspect that the answer is "No", but is there any way to correct these records?

I've tried restarting the phone and monkeying around with the date and time again manually, but there's been no change to the list.

This is an iPhone 5 running iOS 6.0.1

Comment: Interesting bug / failure. I wonder if your carrier was sending bad call date timestamps or perhaps your device was set to set time automatically. If so, it's plausible a bad time server could have told your phone the time was ahead and now that's fixed.

Comment: @bmike: Sorry, I guess "messing around" isn't very descriptive. I had switched "Set time automatically" _off_, and changed the phone's date manually, probably to 1/12 though I don't recall exactly, and left it that way (actually forgot about it) for a while. It seems to me like the time stamps were generated locally. Then again, I know next to nothing about how cell phone calls and records are made. But my phone's time was definitely manually set incorrectly when those calls happened.

Comment: It seems you can answer this conclusively. If you set the time on your iPhone, it uses it to log when calls arrive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's *no* way to change the Recent calls timestamps.

You will either have to wait past the 1/12/13 or you could consider deleting those numbers. Course, you would obviously lose the phone numbers, and that data, but it would keep your true recent calls on top before it starts working again on 1/12/13.

It appears to be indeed changing time on the iPhone that has caused this issue, as I was able to repeat it easily. In testing it, I switched off "automatic" time, and change the date to tomorrow. After that, I made a phone call and then changed it back to set the time automatically. The phone call that I made during the manual time change indicated that I made the call tomorrow. 1/10/13, in this case.

So, your iPhone uses local time - the time that displays on the phone at the top of the screen - to log, order, and display recent calls.